# Mongoose and nodejs: about schema and query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a rest api that allows users to submit and retrieve data produced by surveys: questions are not mandatory and each "submit" could be different from each other. Each submit is a json with data and a "survey id":

```
{
  id: abc123,
  surveyid: 123,
  array: [],
  object: {}
  ...
}
```

I have to store this data and allow retrieving and querying.

First approach: going without schema and putting everything in a single collection: it works, but each json field is treated as a "String" and making queries on numeric values is problematic.

Second approach: get questions datatypes for each survey, make/save a mongoose schema on a json file and then keep updated this file.
Something like this, where entry "schema : {}" represent a mongoose schema used for inserting and querying/retrieving data.

```
[ 
  {
    "surveyid" : "123",
    "schema" :   {
        "name": "string",
        "username" : "string",
        "value" : "number",
        "start": "date",
        "bool" : "boolean",
        ...
    }
  },
  { ... }
]
```

Hoping this is clear, I've some questions:

1. Right now I've a single collection for all "submits" and everything is treated as a string. Can I use a mongoose schema, without other modifications, in order to specify that some fields are numeric (or date or whatever)? Is it allowed or is it even a good idea?
2. Are there any disadvantage using an external json file? Mongoose schemas are loaded at run time when requested or does the service need to be restart when this file is updated?
3. How to store data with a "schema" that could change often ?

I hope it's clear!

Thank you!

Comment: For 1 Point, You can do  and its allowed in mongodb, 2 Point-- reading and writing on file  can be faster than your query and also depend on the size collection...

Comment: Thank you, so I can change schema and mongoose will treat what's inside mongo collection according to the schema I passed in? If I saved it as a String and later I specify that is an Date instead, it will be parsed/returned as a Date?

Comment: Moreover, I didn't understand your reply about point 2, maybe I was not clear: usually you define mongoose schema along other stuff. What if you move the schema declaration, in its json format, in a separate file? When a request comes, you pick up the right schema and execute the requested action. In this way you can, for example, update schemas periodically with a script, is that right/possible? Do I need to restart app when a schema changes? Thanks!